# CGRect var as property value?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

CGRect type is a structure type. If I want to define a property as this type, should I use assign or retain attribute for this type?

```
@interface MyClass {
  CGRect rect;
  ...
}
@property (nonatomic, assign) CGRect rect; // or retain?
```

or I have to write my own getter and setter?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Only `assign` is possible for non-objects. (Before ARC, that includes CoreFoundation stuff, e.g. a CFArrayRef can only be `assign`.)

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) CGRect rect;
//                            ^^^^^^ don't forget.
```

You don't need a custom getter and setter unless you don't want to use `memcpy` for assignment.

Comment: Thanks. Do I need to have my own setting to assign field by field in code?

Comment: @David: If it's CGRect, assigning field by field is equivalent to `memcpy`.

Comment: How do you set the rect... Its confusing me

Comment: @KennyTM How did this change with ARC? I was (am) under the assumption that ARC (at least in current clang 3.3) does not know about CoreFoundation ownership rules.

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16022019/assign-properties-arc-and-core-foundation-objects

Comment: The linked post does not imply a change of rules for Core Foundation when using ARC. It just gives a hint to use retainable-object-rules on non-retainable-object types by decorating the type with `__attribute__((NSObject))`.

Answer (score 1):

```
@property (assign) CGRect rect;
```

`CGrect` is a struct, not an `NSObject`, so you cannot send message to it (like `retain`).

You're full setup then will be something like:

```
// MyClass.h
@interface MyClass : NSObject
{
    CGRect _rect;
}

@property (assign) CGRect rect;
```

and

```
// MyClass.m
@implementation MyClass

@synthesize rect=_rect;

@end
```

So basically you can then do something like:

```
MyClass *myClass = [[MyClass alloc] init];
myClass.rect = CGRectMake(0,0,0,0);
```

The synthesize directive basically makes two methods (getter/setter) for you "behind the scenes"; something like...

```
- (CGRect)rect;
- (void)setRect:(CGRect)value;
```

I usually add a "_" to my instance vars. The `rect=_rect` is telling the compiler to modify the _rect instance var whenever the rect property is "called."

Have a read through [these tutorials on Theocaco](http://theocacao.com/document.page/510). He explains what the @synthesize(r) is doing behind the scenes.

Comment: That makes sense. Still not sure what is the generated codes to do the assignment, memory or field-by-field? I edited my question.