# assign properties, ARC and Core Foundation objects

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, core-foundation

### Edit 2.

Thanks to [Ken](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1312143/ken-thomases) this is now working. And I even think I understand why :-)

Here's the amended line:

```
- (void) reCreatePath {
    CGMutablePathRef p = ::CGPathCreateMutable() ;

    ::CGPathMoveToPoint         (p, 0, TL.x, TL.y) ;
    // [snip]
    ::CGPathAddLineToPoint      (p, 0, BL.x, BL.y) ;
    ::CGPathCloseSubpath(p) ;


    self.path = p ;
    ::CGPathRelease(p) ;   // <<== THIS IS IT!! :-)
}
```

### Edit.

I still don't get it. I tried Chuck suggestion:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) __attribute__((NSObject)) CGPathRef  path ;
```

Like so:

```
@interface TopLeftSlidingView  ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) __attribute__((NSObject)) CGPathRef  path ;

@end
```

And at the point where I recreate the CGPath:

```
- (void) reCreatePath {
    CGMutablePathRef p = ::CGPathCreateMutable() ;

    ::CGPathMoveToPoint         (p, 0, TL.x, TL.y) ;
    // [snip]
    ::CGPathAddLineToPoint      (p, 0, BL.x, BL.y) ;
    ::CGPathCloseSubpath(p) ;


//    self.path = (__bridge CGMutablePathRef) p ;
//    self.path = (__bridge_transfer CGMutablePathRef) p ;
//    self.path = (__bridge_retained CGMutablePathRef) p ;
    self.path = p ;
}
```

Either of the three commented out lines results in a compiler error.
The non commented line does compile, but generates an analyser warning:

```
/Users/verec/Projects/WordGame/WordGame/classes/TopLeftSlidingView.mm:211:26:
 Call to function 'CGPathCreateMutable' returns a Core Foundation object with
 a +1 retain count
```

followed by:

```
/Users/verec/Projects/WordGame/WordGame/classes/TopLeftSlidingView.mm:225:5:
 Object leaked: object allocated and stored into 'p' is not referenced later 
 in this execution path and has a retain count of +1
```

I just do not get it :(

---

Consider:

```
@interface Test : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, assign) CGColorRef color ;

@end

@implementation Test

- (void) dealloc {
    if (self.color) {
        ::CGColorRelease(self.color) ;
        self.color = 0 ;
    }
}

- (id) init {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        self.color = ::CGColorRetain([UIColor blueColor].CGColor) ;
    }
    return self ;
}

@end
```

This all compiles (and seemingly runs) fine except that the analyser keeps reporting warnings.

In essence what this code is saying is: "Please ARC, don't bother doing anything at all with `color`, please treat it the way you'd treat any other `assign` property, be it an BOOL or CGFloat, I'm handling memory management all by my own!"

Except that ARC refuses to listen to me and still complains!

I have read many questions here on SO, but none of them seem to address this issue ...

The key thing here, and the compiler (though not the analyser) seems to agree, is that by declaring the property `assign' I have claimed to handle it all on my own...

So I must be wrong, but I just don't see why ...

What's wrong?

Comment: if you want to manage everything by yours, then certainly you dont need property, you can go with ivar and create setters and getters.

Comment: I'm kind of feeling like the analyzer has a point here. Do you have accessors for `color`?

Comment: @ anoop Such a good answer! You should make it a proper reply so that I can accept it! :-) @ chuck as soon as you declare a property Xcode now synthesises the getters/setters for you. Maybe I could add a @dynamic? But why does ARC bother with assign properties at all?

Comment: @verec: Chuck is always good.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you're using the automatically synthesized getters and setters, there is indeed a memory management problem here. In the setter, your CGColor needs to be released and the new value retained, but the `assign` accessor will not do this for you — it literally just assigns the new pointer value to the variable. You'll need to implement your own accessors in order to manage the memory correctly.

However, if you'd like, ARC can handle this for you instead of you having to do it yourself. Just declare it like so:

```
@property(nonatomic, strong) __attribute__((NSObject)) CGColorRef color;
```

Comment: Thanks for the __attribute__ ((NSObject)) in case I'd want ARC to manage it for me, but I still do not understand why the setter of an *assign* property could legitimately do anything at all regarding memory management. Does ARC inspect every single assign property for CF data types? And just gives up when it sees a scalar? What's the point?

Comment: I think it is the static analyzer. In `self.color = CGColorRetain(..)`, which is the same as `[self setColor:CGColorRetain(..)]`,  it does not know that the retain is balanced later in `dealloc`.

Comment: I think I get it now. The thing is that because it is a property, it could be used by KVO by someone outside my implementation, that would have no idea that the thing needs special care (and wouldn't be able to provide it if they did). Hence making it a property-less ivar as @anoop suggested is probably the safest bet. Thank you all for clarifying this! :)

Comment: @verec: That's the point. The generated property setter *won't* do anything to manage your memory, but your CGColor *needs* a setter that does memory management. If you are going to do all the memory management outside of setter methods, yes, an ivar would make more sense. But if this variable is going to be set outside of init and dealloc, using a setter would be a good idea, as it greatly simplifies memory management. If you use a simple ivar instead, it takes the setter's responsibility and spreads it to every part of your code that touches the variable. That's a lot of responsibility!

Comment: @Chuck: How would you define a setter such that the static analyzer does not complain on `self.color = CGColorRetain(..)` (as you suggested in the first paragraph of your answer)? - The `__attribute__((NSObject))` works because `UIColor` is toll-free brigded to `CGColorRef` and would not work with all CF objects, is that correct?

Comment: @MartinR: `__attribute__((NSObject))` works for all CoreFoundation objects. For example, it's used with a number of non-bridged types in Apple's AVFoundation framework (e.g. CMClock). At any rate, if you're going to do the management yourself, the correct semantics for using a setter would be to have the memory management in the setter. Do you think I should be clearer about that?

Comment: @Chuck: First of all, thank you for the information. I didn't know that attribute and have to read about it (do you have a link at hand?). I am only interested because I tried to answer a [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15861222/how-to-properly-handle-cf-objects-created-at-the-beginning-of-the-program-and-de), and finally recommended to use the ivar for creation and release. Before giving that answer, I tried to write a setter function, but failed. You would have to tell the compiler/analyzer that the accessor "balances" the CFRetain, but how?

Comment: @Chuck: OK, I have found __attribute__((NSObject)) in the Clang/ARC documentation, that seems to answer my questions.

Comment: @Chuck: I edited the question. I applied the __attribute__((NSObject)) thing, but still get analyser complaints.

Comment: You are still responsible for correct local memory management. In this case, you have to `CGPathRelease(p);` after assigning to the property. The property is properly memory-managed but that doesn't take care of the local.