# I want to declare a property for CFStringRef, how can I do?

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

Generally, we delare property like this:

```
@Property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * string;
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger  number;
```

But if I want to declare a CF object, how can I do?
Is it the same under ARC?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@property(nonatomic, strong) __attribute__((NSObject)) CFStringRef myString;
```

This way, ARC will do all the work for you.

Because there is tollfree bridging between NSString and CFStringRef, you could also do:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *myString;
```

and when setting the property with a CFStringRef:

```
CFStringRef myStringRef = CFSTR("Hello!");

myObject.myString = (__bridge_transfer NSString *)myStringRef;
```

See also: http://amattn.com/2011/12/07/arc_best_practices.html

and: [assign properties, ARC and Core Foundation objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16022019/assign-properties-arc-and-core-foundation-objects)

Comment: Since CF objects are not managed by ARC you should also take care of them in a dealloc method. Normally under ARC you don't need to implement dealloc but with CF objects you should.

Comment: @Marcel Hello, Marcel. Do you mean that is the same as "assign"?

Comment: @uchuugaka Yeah, I know that I should use CFRelease() for the CF objects in dealloc method, but without invoke [super dealloc]; Thanks for your explanation. However, I am confusing that which following ways shall I take.
NO.1
\@interface MyClass
 {
    CFStringRef myStringRef;
}
No.2
\@Property (nonatomic) CFStringRef stringRef;

Comment: Hence, cast them to an NSString object and let ARC do the rest.

Comment: @Marcel Yeah, Just casting CFStringRef to NSString is very well. But this is one of many cases. If I want to use a property of CFSocketRef, how can I do?

Comment: @Marcel I just have another question, please help me. NO.1 \@interface MyClass { CFSocketRef mySocketRef; } \@end No.2 \@Property (nonatomic) CFSocketRef mySocketRef; Is No.1 the same as No.2?

Comment: No, n1 is an instance var, you would have to create getters and setters yourself. n2 is a property, getters and setters are automatic, so is memory.

Comment: This is discussed in detail in the guide to ARC.

Comment: @uchuugaka Thank u, I'l check the guide to ARC again right now.