# Memory issue with PDF Pages drawn to view iOS 6.1

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6

I've got some memory issue on a simple iPad/iPhone app that should display a (large) PDF. Here is what I do.

I've got a scrollView with 5 subviews. Each subview displays a page of my PDF. One page is always displayed, 2 pages on each side are preloaded. If you scroll, a no-more-needed view is taken, the new PDF page to preload is rendered and the view is repositioned inside the scrollView.

Everything works really fine except that memory issue. If I profile memory leaks, the live bytes grow from 4MB to 40MB+. The overall bytes grow up to 600 MB+.
I think the live bytes should not really grow, as I have the same 5 views at any time. Or am I reading the values incorrect?

ARC is used.

This is the code that renders the PDF pages.

```
-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)inRect{
    self.ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSaveGState(self.ctx);

    CGRect cropBox = CGPDFPageGetBoxRect(self.pdfPage, kCGPDFCropBox);
    CGRect targetRect = [self bounds];
    CGFloat xScale = targetRect.size.width / cropBox.size.width;
    CGFloat yScale = targetRect.size.height / cropBox.size.height;
    CGFloat scaleToApply = xScale < yScale ? xScale : yScale;
    CGFloat newWidth = cropBox.size.width * scaleToApply;
    CGFloat newHeight = cropBox.size.height * scaleToApply;
    CGFloat xOffset = (targetRect.size.width - newWidth) / 2;
    CGFloat yOffset = (targetRect.size.height - newHeight) / 2;

    CGContextTranslateCTM(self.ctx, xOffset, [self bounds].size.height - yOffset);
    CGContextScaleCTM(self.ctx, 1.0, -1.0);
    CGContextConcatCTM(self.ctx, CGAffineTransformMakeScale(scaleToApply, scaleToApply));
    CGContextSetInterpolationQuality(self.ctx, kCGInterpolationHigh);
    CGContextSetRenderingIntent(self.ctx, kCGRenderingIntentDefault);
    CGContextDrawPDFPage(self.ctx, self.pdfPage);

    CGContextRestoreGState(self.ctx);
}
```

And this is the method that makes the view rerender to a new PDF page, if the old is no more needed.

```
- (void)redrawPdfPage:(CGPDFPageRef)pPdfPage withPageNum:(int)pPageNum {
    self.pdfPage = pPdfPage;
    self.pageNum = pPageNum;
    CGRect r = [self frame];
    r.origin.x = r.size.width * (self.pageNum - 1);
    [self setFrame:r];
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

Any advice on this will be appreciated, as I'm trying to figure out how to free the memory of the old PDF pages for days...

Comment: Did you consider simply using UIDocumentInteractionController to show PDF files?

Comment: Yes some sort of. But I need to be flexible in functionality and design of the viewed pdf pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With ARC you still have to put some effort into managing Foundation objects. You can release old page using `CGPDFPageRelease`. Or you can add appropriate attribute to your `pdfPage` property declaration, as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16022585/2128900).